# How do I assign a variable to a thing in roblox?

Tags: roblox

- There is a variable called f, And this code is supposed to play random audio whenever it's clicked

```
local clickDetector = script.Parent.ClickDetector
f = math.random(1,3)
function onMouseClick()
    
    script.Parent.f.TimePosition = 0
    script.Parent.f.Playing = true
end

clickDetector.MouseClick:connect(onMouseClick)
```

- How do I make it so it will thing it's not inside

Comment: Are `script.Parent[1]`, `script.Parent[2]`, and `script.Parent[3]` all [Sound objects](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Sound)?

Comment: Try `script.Parent[f]`

Answer (score 0):

assuming the parent exist, try
script.Parent[f]